# excel vba - finding a value of a cell in a column and recording what text is in the another column of the corresponding row

Tags: excel, vba

I love excel and can write very basic macros, but want to do something more complicated that would make getting information out to my students very efficient.

imagine the data below is a grade book. Column A is the list of homework assignments and then each next column is a student with their grades for each assignment.

```
    |    A     |   B
 ---------------------
 1. | student: | Nick 
 2. | HW2 ---  |  0  
 3. | HW3 ---  |  0
 4. | HW4 ---  |  3
 5. | HW5 ---  |  0
```

I want to be able to select a student's name, then hit a button that will record the list of assignments from column A that corresponds to any row under the students name that has a "0" in it...the goal then being that this list of assignments can be put in the body of an email.
I have a function written that will cause an email to appear but I can't figure out the code for a function that will collect the "0 on HW" data that I can put in the body of that email.

I appreciate any help.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
Sub Grade_0()
    Name = ActiveCell
    Set Sheet = ActiveCell.Worksheet
    List = ""
    With Sheet
        colOffset = ActiveCell.Column - 1
        For Each cell In .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
            If cell.Offset(0, colOffset) = 0 Then
                List = List + cell + " "
            End If
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox List
End Sub
```

It's just a demonstration to find the assignments. You have to how to queue and return them the right way.